# Load (Performance) Testing of Single Page Application (SPA)

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, performance-testing

I want to perform Load (Performance) Testing of Single Page Application (SPA). Also want to record the performance metrics. I have found that JMeter performs load testing for API calls but not actual browser for SPA.

Could you please suggest any opensource or paid alternatives which i can use to perform load testing of SPA for concurrent 500 users.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "actual browser"?

Given **you** [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) there won't be any difference from the "SPA" whether it's accessed by JMeter or by the real "actual browser"

If your requirement is to use 500 "actual browsers" for testing your SPA you can take a look at [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework.

But remember about browser resources footprint and the fact you won't be able to collect the majority of [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) using this approach.

Comment: HI Dmitri,   I want to test performance of SPA when 500 concurrent users will access the site.   in that want to test performance for API calls +  actual end user browsers performance.  Need to track this. Thanks